# How do I limit form options based on previous entry & leave all fields (including file selection) populated on submittion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have the current form:

```
<form name="estimate" action="live_preview.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Upload File 1:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <label for="qty1">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="qty1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="file">Upload File 2:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"/>
    <label for="qty2">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="qty2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="file">Upload File 3:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3"/>
    <label for="qty3">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="qty3">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="file">Upload File 4:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file4" id="file4"/>
    <label for="qty4">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="qty4">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="file">Upload File 5:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file5" id="file5"/>
    <label for="qty5">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="qty5">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="meterial">Meterial:</label>
    <select name="material">
        <option value="PLA">PLA (0.60$ / Gram)</option>
        <option value="ABS">ABS (0.60$ / Gram)</option>
        <option value="POLYCARB">PolyCarb (1.80$ / Gram)</option>
        <option value="NYLON">Nylon (1.20$ / Gram)</option>
    </select>
    |
    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select name="color">
        <option value="WHITE">White</option>
        <option value="BLACK">Black</option>
        <option value="RED">Red</option>
        <option value="GREEN">Green</option>
        <option value="GRAY">Gray</option>
    </select>
    |
    <label for="delivery">Delivery Method:</label>
    <select name="delivery">
        <option value="PICK UP">Pick Up (Free)</option>
        <option value="SHIPPED">Shipped (+10$)</option>
    </select>
    |
    <label for="marketing">Marketing?</label>
    <select name="marketing">
        <option value="YES">YES</option>
        <option value="NO">NO</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="infill">Infill: 20%</label>
    <input type="range" name="infill" id="infill" value="20" min="20" max="90" step="10" onchange="printValue('infill','rangeValue1')"/>
    90%
    <input id="rangeValue1" type="text" size="2"/>
    <br>
    <ul class="buttons vertical">
        <input type="submit" class="button fit scrolly" name="submit" value="Refresh Estimate" />
    </ul>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Being able to limit the colour selection based on the type of material previously chosen
2. Upon submission, process php file while still keeping all fields populated so that if user isn't happy with price given, they can modify some settings and get a new "estimate"
3. have the following actions happen w/o a page refresh (not a priority)

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this! Its extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

This would be achieved with **client-side** code. Javascript / jQuery is what you need here.

**2.**

Unfortunately, file fields can't be kept populated when you reload the page (or redirect back). You can keep them populated by using **AJAX** to send your form contents, but it can be quite complex and sending files with AJAX will only work in modern browsers.

**3.**

**AJAX** is what you are looking for if you want server actions to happen without a page refresh. Look at jQuery [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). My suggestion is that you have your form which people begin to fill out. The site will check the inputs along the way and suggest prices without refreshing the page, and once they are happy and ready to go, they submit the form which will upload the files and "refresh the page".

Answer (score 0):

on 2, php only solution: You can keep the fields populated on submission by adding a placeholder to the input field. The placeholder gets the submitted value ($_POST('value') or similar). Just make sure that the value isn't lost if you have several fields and thus several submits before the customer hits the final "all fine" button, maybe use $_SESSION for that.